# Xamarin Forms de-serialization error on Windows Phone 10 physical device and emulator

Tags: c#, serialization, enums, xamarin.forms

I have an app in which I save settings to the local app storage on each device.  I use the 
    Application.Current.Properties
approach to reading and saving data.  The challenge I am having is that one of the values I save is an enum that I have defined in my App.xaml.cs file but before the actual
    public partial class App : Application
declaration.

The challenge I am having is that on any Windows Phone 10 device (physical or emulator), I can only run the application once (when I initially debug it.) If I attempt to launch the application again I am receiving an error that my settings couldn't be loaded because my enum value could not be de-serialized.  The exact error message is below.

**Exception thrown: 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' in  SYSTEM.RUNTIME.SERIALIZATION.NI.DLL**

Additional information: Error in line 1 position 3583. Element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays:Value' contains data of the 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/XXXXX:ge_AppMode' data contract. The deserializer has no knowledge of any type that maps to this contract. Add the type corresponding to 'ge_AppMode' to the list of known types - for example, by using the KnownTypeAttribute attribute or by adding it to the list of known types passed to DataContractSerializer.

Any idea how to fix this so I can test on the Windows Phone 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I am going to open this as a defect against Xamarin Forms.  Basically the only way I could get it to work was to:

1. Uninstall the app
2. Reboot the phone
3. Change the type of the value that was saved in the properties to an integer.

Then every time I access the Int value I cast if back to the enum I need.  It is a pain but it seems to work in the WP 8.1 app now.  I hope this helps other people and Microsoft if you read this - please fix this issue in Xamarin Forms.